# Url rewrite in exception middleware

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, exception, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm trying to do some custom exception handling and in there I need to redirect.

They way to go should be like this

```
            app.UseExceptionHandler(appBuilder =>
            {                
                appBuilder.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
                {
                    ctx.Request.Path = "/Error";
                    await next();
                });
            });
```

But nothing happens, just a blank 500 page.

Any ideas except the use of

```
ctx.Response.Redirect("/Error")
```

Comment: Try to write like this app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

Comment: ```await next(ctx);``` can u try that

Comment: @AntonDikarev That would just trigger the existing exception handler logic. I want to write my own since I have specific needs.

Comment: @BerkGarip next() doesn't allow my to input a parameter. Delegate Func<Task> does not take 1 arguments

Comment: @cds Any update? Does my reply help you?

Comment: Hi, I ended up using ExceptionHandlerMiddleware as my base to start from for writing my own exception middleware. Cleaned out some unnecessary logging, options, etc and expanded it with what I needed. And for now it seems to be holding up.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the overload of `UseExceptionHandler` accepting an `Action<IApplicationBuilder>`, you need to configure a full pipeline for the sub-builder inside to re-execute the pipeline on the exception branch. In your code, you just set the `Request.Path` but it is then not handled by any code. You need to add an MVC middleware as the terminal at the end. You can configure it just like you configure your main pipeline (`UseMvc`, `UseEndpoints`). In this case the terminal just need to work with the specific request path you set before. Here's the code:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(appBuilder => {                
      appBuilder.Use(async (ctx, next) => {
          ctx.Request.Path = "/Error";
          await next();
      });
      //add the terminal to handle the branched request
      appBuilder.UseMvc();
});
```

Now when you run into some unhandled exception, it should work just like `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error")`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could firstly try to understand how the exceptionhanlder works.

According to the [source codes](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerExtensions.cs), you could find if you want to write the custom  middleware ,you should use the second function like this:

```
   public static IApplicationBuilder UseExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder app, Action<IApplicationBuilder> configure)
    {
        if (app == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
        }
        if (configure == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configure));
        }

        var subAppBuilder = app.New();
        configure(subAppBuilder);
        var exceptionHandlerPipeline = subAppBuilder.Build();

        return app.UseExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandlerOptions
        {
            ExceptionHandler = exceptionHandlerPipeline
        });
    }
```

If you use this function, you could find it will still call the ExceptionHandlerMiddleware with its new exceptionHandlerPipeline. And in the [ExceptionHandlerMiddleware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs#L133) , you could find it will call this request delaget.

So if you don't catch the exception and directly set the context path it will not work. So I suggest you could try to use below codes:

```
        app.UseExceptionHandler(appBuilder =>
        {
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await next();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ClearHttpContext(context);
                    var exceptionHandlerFeature = new ExceptionHandlerFeature()
                    {
                        Error =  ex,
                        Path = "/Home/Index",
                    };
                    context.Request.Path = "/Home/Error";
                    context.Features.Set<IExceptionHandlerFeature>(exceptionHandlerFeature);
                    context.Features.Set<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>(exceptionHandlerFeature);
                    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
                    context.Response.OnStarting(ClearCacheHeaders, context.Response);
                    await next();
                }
            });
        });
```

ClearCacheHeaders method:

```
    private static Task ClearCacheHeaders(object state)
    {
        var headers = ((HttpResponse)state).Headers;
        headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = "no-cache,no-store";
        headers[HeaderNames.Pragma] = "no-cache";
        headers[HeaderNames.Expires] = "-1";
        headers.Remove(HeaderNames.ETag);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```