# Generic Exception Filter to Display error message on Specific Controller Action's View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DoSomething(Some thing)
{
  try
  {
     return View (message);
  }
  catch (Exception) { return View (message); }
}
```

I want to catch the exception and want to pass the custom error message to the **View**. I don't want to add `try catch` block in every action method. Is there a way to catch exception globally and **fetch exception** in the *controller* action and return the error message to the specific action's **View**. I.e. I do not want to **catch exception** globally and end up to error page.
It will be very helpful if someone give me a overview or basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could consider using the `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");` to achieve your requirement.

The ExceptionHandler could capture the exception which thrown by your controller codes and then it will rewrite to Home error action instead of directly return to the client side.

More details about how to use it, you could refer to below codes:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseSession();   
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
         });
    }
```

The error action codes:

```
    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
```

Also if you want to customsize this ExceptionHandler, I suggest you could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66759248/7609093). I make a custom exception handler middleware and rewrite the response to error action method.